# row_number over partition at Version < Firebird 3

Tags: firebird, window-functions

I´m currently at the end. 
 Given facts:

```
ID      ID2      FROM                TO                 COSTS
4985  501671  2013-07-25 00:00:00  2013-12-30 00:00:00   17.8
4985  501671  2013-09-05 00:00:00  2013-10-24 00:00:00    1.1   
4985  501671  2013-10-25 00:00:00  2013-10-25 00:00:00    1.61  
4985  501671  2013-11-04 00:00:00  2013-12-23 00:00:00    1.9   
4985  501671  2013-12-30 00:00:00  2014-01-10 00:00:00    2.7   
4985  501671  2014-01-06 00:00:00  2014-01-10 00:00:00   18.8
```

Now, I want to sum fields, which are in the same time, eg.

> Row 1 -> from 2013-07-25 till 2013-09-04 and Costs 17.8 because than
>   17.8 must be added with  1.1 Row 2 -> from  2013-09-05 till 2013-10-24 18.80 (17.8 + 1.1) because 1.1 and 17.8 are in the thame time.

Normally, I will `row_number over partition by` but these function is not implemented in Firebird 2.5 :-(

Does anybody know an alternative function to solve this problem?

Comment: You want `SUM(costs) OVER(ORDER BY "from")` for the running total, not `row_number()` If the `"to"` column is to be considered for the totals, it will be even more complicated.

Comment: Hmm okay, but over is Not Supported too, or isnt it?

Comment: No, of course not, `OVER ()` and window functions go hand by hand. Can you add in your question, the expected results for this data?

Comment: of course, imaging following:

Comment: We can't see anything.

Comment: of course, imaging following: A price for a pice of sugar costs from 2013-07-25 till 2013-12-30 2 euros. At the time up from 2013-09-05 there is an addition of 0.50 euros. but at 2013-10-25 there is an other addition, 1.10 euros. The result must be 3 rows for that

Comment: Edit the question please and put the wanted output in a table format.

Answer (score 2):

Hard to tell what you want (a precise question gets a precise answer, a vague question at best gets a lucky guess). In Firebird 2.5 an answer may be something like:

```
EXECUTE BLOCK RETURNS (ID INTEGER, ID2 INTEGER, FROM DATE, TO DATE, 
                        COSTS DECIMAL(9,2), MySUM(DECIMAL(9,2))
AS
DECLARE VARIABLE FROMDATE DATE;
DECLARE VARIABLE TODATE DATE;
BEGIN
  FROMDATE = NULL;
  TODATE = NULL;
  MySUM = 0;
  FOR SELECT ID, ID2, FROM, TO, COSTS
      FROM MyTable
      INTO :ID, :ID2, :FROM, :TO, :COSTS DO
  BEGIN
    IF (FROMDATE <= FROM and TODATE >= TO) THEN
    BEGIN
      MySUM = MySUM + COSTS;
      SUSPEND;
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
      MySUM = COSTS;
      FROMDATE = FROM;
      TODATE = TO;
    END
    SUSPEND;
  END
END
```

By the way, I don't think the above would quite compile since 'FROM' and 'TO' are not names I would recommend as names of columns.

Still, HTH,
Set